# Typescript: I have an object set with user-ids with multiple possible occurrence dates. The requirement is to fetch the minimum date for a given id?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to filter an object set of user id and occurrence dates , i have start date and end date as parameters, and i wish to filter my object set such that occurrence date is between start date and end date.

```
    @Function()
public async fetchPats(startDate: LocalDate, endDate: LocalDate) :  Promise<ObjectSet<RaceLinkedPatients>>{
    const Pat = 
        Objects.search()
        .raceLinkedPatients()
        .filter(p => Filters.or(
            p.fstDt.exactMatch(startDate)
            ))
    return Pat
}
```

Comment: I found the answer

Comment: Filters.and(
                    p.fstDt.range().lte(endDate),
                    p.fstDt.range().gte(startDate),
                )

Comment: Range filters have a set of .lt(), .lte(), .gt() and gte() methods for performing less than / less than or equal to / greater than / greater than or equal to (respectively) comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Range filters have a set of .lt(), .lte(), .gt() and gte() methods for performing less than / less than or equal to / greater than / greater than or equal to (respectively) comparisons

```
Filters.and( p.fstDt.range().lte(endDate), p.fstDt.range().gte(startDate), )
```